# Why am I getting Unspecified error 80004005 when copying from a Samba share to a Windows computer?

Tags: network-shares, samba, shared-folders

I'm copying a large directory structure from a web server to Windows.

This is not for the common reason that I need to install SMB 1.0/CIFS like so:

[image: SMB 1.0 support]

It appears this is a common error message with many different causes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for duplicate names where only the case of the letters is different.

It turns out that I had two directories with the same name, only the case was different!

```
fcc
FCC
```

On Linux, these are different directories. On Windows, they shouldn't exist separately. Copying them from a Linux share caused this error.